# View screen misalignment on Real Device

Tags: swift5

I am having an issue where my app is not loading properly on my real device, even though it loads properly on the simulator. Is there something I’m missing?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us screenshots please? And code regarding the view would probably help us.

Comment: Sorry. I did not set up the link correctly. My apologies.

Comment: Haha! A photo of your phone is definitely one way to go. Can you show us any code? It almost looks as if the width of the screen is set in pixels and is wider than the device.

Comment: What code do you need? I think that might actually be the issue!

Comment: Did you write this in Swift code or did you use a drag-and-drop/wysiwyg editor?

Comment: It's coded in swift. The only drag and drop was to place the UI's on the view.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to change the UI elements to follow constraints. This link has instructions on how to use "Auto Layout" to make your UI elements follow rules or "constraints" rather than being "x pixels wide" and "x pixels from the left".

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html

Search "Adopt Auto Layout" in the page, it's pretty far down.